# Setting hero/splash section as a blog post

Tags: theme-development, loop, templates

I have a hero section on the homepage of my blog that I'd like to be the **main post** and thereafter more posts with a different styles underneath, see below layout: [image: layout].

I'm not sure how to really approach this and need some guidance in the best way to port this into WordPress. Here is the code I have so far in my `index.php` file. I have managed to output the posts below the **hero** but not sure how to approach the main post in the hero/splash section.

```
<div id="main">

    <!-- hero starts here --> 

        <div class="hero">
                <div class="hero-wrapper">
                    <div class="article-info">
                        <p class="topic"><a href="">Culture</a></p> 
                        <h1 class="hero-title"><a href="">Title</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
         </div>


    <!-- Hero end here --> 


    <div class="main-container">

     <!-- Posts starts here -->
        <div class="posts">

            <div class="posts__post">
                <article>

                  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <a class="posts__post--preview" href=""><img src="https://placeimg.com/470/310/tech" /></a>
                    <a class="posts__post--tag" href=""><p>Motivation</p></a>
                    <a class="posts__post--title" href="" ><h1>A Good Autoresponder, some more text here</h1></a>
                    <p class="posts__post--meta"> 10 days ago</p>
                </article>

              <?php endwhile; else : ?>
              <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
              <?php endif; ?>

            </div>

   </div>

    <!-- Posts ends here -->

    <!-- Main ends here -->
```

**Things i'm thinking about:**

1. What happens if I add a new main post? Will the previous post be
   pushed underneath?

Comment: Do you want a new post to become the hero post? Or should the hero post be selected by the site content maintainers?

Comment: This is something i've had in mind too. I think the hero post should be selected by the site content maintainer. This provides more flexibility.

Comment: Then I'd recommend @cjbj 's answer or a variation on it.

Comment: i will give it a go but why do you recommend that answer? and what variation do you have in mind?

Comment: Because WP already gives you the sticky function, so you can get what you want fairly easily as long as no-one makes more than one post sticky.  Variations might be to change the sticky post interface in admin to only ever allow one sticky post, hook into saving posts and if this post is sticky then remove the stickiness from others so only one post is ever sticky or add your own custom field and interface to mark a post as the hero post.

Comment: Can you submit an answer. thats exactly what I need. What would be the best solution if I wanted a new post to become the hero post?

Comment: Well I suggested 3 variations, so I'm not sure which is "exactly what you need." You ought to be able to modify the answer from @cjbj to fit any of those anyway.

Comment: I need there to be one sticky post. If an end user creates an additional sticky then the previous sticky should be removed and turned into a normal post

Answer (score 1):

Code below loop through posts to find a post with ID == 1, then prints it. Second loop show latest 6 posts (hero post will be not shown again because of if block)

```
<div id="main">

    <!-- hero starts here -->

    <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array("posts_per_page" => -1);
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :   $the_query->the_post();
      if ($post->ID == 1 ): ?>
        <div class="hero">
          <div class="hero-wrapper">
            <div class="article-info">
              <p class="topic"><a href=" ">Culture</a></p>
              <h1 class="hero-title"><a href="">Hero post: <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <div class="main-container">

   <!-- Posts starts here -->
    <div class="posts">
      <div class="posts__post">
        <?php $args = array("posts_per_page" => 6);
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :   $the_query->the_post();
            if($post->ID !== 1): ?>
            <article>
              <a class="posts__post--preview" href=" "><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"></a>
              <a class="posts__post--title" href="" ><h2>Non hero: <?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
              <p class="posts__post--excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
              <?php echo "<p>post ID: " . $post->ID . "</p>"; ?>
            </article>
            <?php endif;
          endwhile; ?>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Sorry I misundersood your question, now it should be okay.
P.S.2 You should not edit "index.php" file, if you want to do this right way read about template hierarchy etc. 
Useful scheme: [image]

Comment: But it's extremely unlikely that the OP wants to display the post with ID == 1 as the hero post.  Most likely post #1 will be the WP default installation first post or will be an auto-saved revision.

Comment: You're right, but it is only a concept, the best way to achieve this goal would be to create custom meta box "Show as hero post" then display it (and exclude from posts loop).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do difficult stuff if you use the [`sticky`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts) feature, which allows you to label one or more posts to be pushed up the stack. With a checkbox in the admin you can thus determine which post must be the 'hero'.

You then use a simple loop to output all your posts. The stickies will always remain on top, also when you add new posts.

If you set `width:100%;` on the post with class sticky and `width:48%; float:left;` on the other posts, you have the setup you want.

UPDATE

If you want to keep your html portions separate, you will need a different loop that just returns the first sticky post, like this ([docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)):

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $sticky[0] ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); 
    ... do loop stuff ..
    }
  wp_reset_postdata(); // resetting for the main query
  }
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about this solution.. but your advising me to remove my hero section all together? or simply start my loop where my hero section starts? I'm trying to keep the structure as above. my other concern is what if by mistake two sticky posts are made?

Comment: If you don't use `sticky`, you will need another label on posts to make them `hero`. That doesn't really make sense. You do have a point that multiple stickies could be pushed up the stack. That's solvable inside one loop. If you want to keep the html separate as you have, you will need a second loop on your post. I'll update my answer for that.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to WP so still wrapping my head around stuff. So it looks like your storing the sticky post in a variable called `$sticky`. You're then creating a query that accesses the first `sticky` at value 0 and simply checking if there is a `sticky`. if so then output it to Hero. Then have another if statement that loops over the posts. Wouldn't this create a duplicate post that is seen in the hero?

Comment: Yes, unless you tell the query to rule out stickies from that loop. I could spell it out for you, but you'll learn more by following the link to the docs in my answer and see how to achieve this yourself...

Comment: Ha theres literally a section from the doc you provided that says **Don't show sticky posts**. it's still going over my head as i'm a beginner but I will still give it a try.

Comment: I knew that ;-) It's alway difficult in the beginning, but the `wp_query` class is so essential you'll have get familiar with it if you want to be a WP developer. You can take the loop from my answer and play around with the line that says `$query = new WP_Query`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard home page loop will put any sticky posts first, so you may not need special HTML for the hero post , just CSS targeting it.

This code in a plugin or your functions.php will ensure that only one post can be sticky:

```
add_action( 'post_stuck', 'wpse239911_only_one_sticky' );

function wpse239911_only_one_sticky( $post_id ) {
    remove_action( 'post_stuck', 'wpse239911_only_one_sticky' );
    // prevent loop
    delete_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    stick_post( $post_id );
}
```

Whenever a post is made sticky, the function fires, clearing the list of sticky posts and then making the post that triggered the action sticky again.

The removal of the action ensures that calling `stick_post` doesn't plunge us into an eternal abyss.

Comment: Hello. I'd prefer to keep my HTML in tack. I have used two if statements as @cjbj has suggested. I also used your code to prevent multiple stickies however I now have duplication in my posts